# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac { -2x}{(x^2+k^2)^2}$ converges uniformly using the M test.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac { -2x}{(x^2+k^2)^2}$ converges
>   uniformly using the M test.

Comment: Can you explain your thoughts and efforts on the problem? For example, can you give a statement of the $M$ test in your own words?

Comment: Sure. $|\frac {-2x}{(x^2+k^2)^2}| <= |\frac {-2x}{(k^2)^2}|$. I've made very little progress on this. Additionally I've tried working with x's which seems to make more sense and can say that $|\frac {-2x}{(x^2+k^2)^2}| <= |\frac {-2}{x^3}|$

Comment: To me, both cases appear unbounded. I can choose some really small x in case 2 or a really large x in case 1.

Comment: Hint: To use the $M$ test, you need to bound $\frac{|2x|}{(x^2+k^2)^2}$ for all $x$, by a "small enough" expression that depends only on $k$.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I may have just realized something. The M test considers the summation of each individual term, so I can let $M_k = \frac {2}{x^3}$ and then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty M_k < \infty$

Comment: No, you cannot have $M_k$ depend on $x$.  On $k$ only.  Read the [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Comment: Thanks, I will add that to my notes. Then how do I get rid of that x on the top of my fraction in the first case I stated?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x^2+k^2)^2} ~=~ \dfrac\pi{2~x^2}~\bigg[\dfrac{\coth(\pi x)}x+\pi~\text{csch}^2(\pi x)\bigg].$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bound you wrote in a comment is a good start for small $x$.

It is most convenient to split into two cases, where $|x| < 1$ and where $|x| > 1$. In the first (actually always, it's just not useful), we have

$$(x^2 + k^2)^2 \ge k^4$$ so that

$$\left|\frac{-2x}{(x^2 + k^2)^2}\right| \le \frac{2}{k^4}$$

The corresponding series converges, so we have uniform convergence on $[-1, 1]$.

For the second case,

$$(x^2 + k^2)^2 \ge 2x^2 k^2$$

by taking the middle term in the expansion only. [My goal here is to get simultaneously a high power of $k$, to force convergence, and a high power of $x$, to kill off the numerator.] Then

$$\left|\frac{-2x}{(x^2 + k^2)^2}\right| \le \frac{2|x|}{2x^2 k^2} = \frac 1 {|x| k^2} \le \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Again, the corresponding series is convergent. In fact, we could actually now just combine the two cases: We have the bound

$$\left|\frac{-2x}{(x^2 + k^2)^2}\right| \le \frac{2}{k^2}$$

for all $x$.